# Combine three procedures in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Good afternoon,

I am trying to combine the three following VBA segments without any luck. Searching hasn't done me much good. Would appreciate any assistance.

```
Sub UnProtectSheetWithPassword()

Sheets("Sheet2").Unprotect Password:="myPassword

End Sub"
```

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Range("O3").Address Then
        Range("B8:Q507").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("O2:O3")
    End If
End Sub
```

```
Sub ProtectSheetWithPassword()

Sheets("Sheet2").Protect Password:="myPassword"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want ?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Range("O3").Address Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").Unprotect Password:="myPassword"
        Range("B8:Q507").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("O2:O3")
        Sheets("Sheet2").Protect Password:="myPassword"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the very quick reply! But I'm getting the following error:
Subscript out of range

Comment: Replace the `Range()` objects with `Me.Range()` especially the one in `CriteriaRange`. Never use unqualified range objects. If `Sheet2` is the sheet where the `Change` event is then replace `Sheets("Sheet2")` with `Me` too.

Comment: Thank you both very much, the code worked when I did the Me. alterations!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Me.Range("O3").Address Then
        Me.Unprotect Password:="myPassword"
        Me.Range("B8:Q507").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Me.Range("O2:O3")
        Me.Protect Password:="myPassword"
    End If
End Sub
```